# How to dynamically make models after retrieve Firebase database node?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an app connected to Firebase realtime database, My app contains products, every product has options:

[image]

the nodes data has no standards.
how could I make a model for every node, dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no standard for what the data contains, it'll be hard to make any Java class that models for that data. Well... strictly speaking you could probably generate the class at runtime using reflection, but that's a bit beyond what most developers are looking to do in a single application.

You still have two valid options for dealing with this data though:

1. Just use the `DataSnapshot` from Firebase directly in your code. You can loop over the unknown child nodes by using `getChildren()` as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).
2. Extract the value of the `DataSnapshot` into a `Map<String, Object>` and use that in the rest of your code. You can then access specific values with the regular accessor methods of a `Map`.

Both are valid. I'd typically recommend using a `DataSnapshot` if you still need to know the order of the child nodes within it. If order doesn't matter anymore, then you can also safely convert to a `Map` without losing fidelity.

Comment: Thank you Frank, I will use Maps